# pandas Series copy does not create a copy

Tags: pandas, copy, deep-copy

So I got really confused with `pd.Series.copy()` behaviour. 
According to [1](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.copy.html), it shall create a deep copy, so the changing the values for the copy shall leave the orignal row (and dataframe) intact. 
So why the heck this return True?

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():        
    q = row.copy()
    q.col.append(['foo'])
    return row.col == q.col
```

Comment: try with `id(row.col) == id(q.col)` or `row.col is q.col`.

Comment: but I see at the values, that it was added to the original, row.col is [1,2,3] then I append 4 to its copy and boom ... row.col is [1,2,3,4]

Comment: Note also that the behavior of `.append` is different from the base python method. For a pandas series or dataframe, `append` will return the appended object, it will not modify it in place. Therefore, your code did not actually modify q.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should note that q is a pd.Series.

According to  [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Series.copy.html) of pd.Series.copy,

*"Make a deep copy, including a copy of the data and the indices. With deep=False neither the indices or the data are copied.
    Note that when deep=True data is copied, actual python objects will not be copied recursively, only the reference to the object. This is in contrast to copy.deepcopy in the Standard Library, which recursively copies object data."*

That's why only the reference to the list is copied, and not the list itself. You should probably apply a custom function where you manually copy the list.

Comment: this seems like a serious drawback of pandas. I know iterrows is not the best in terms of efficiency, but sometimes is it just natural and anyhow cheap, so I tend to use it here and there.

Comment: Was my answer ok, or do you need the custom function ?